# Resize image before insert - GROCERY CRUD/CODE IGNITER

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I'm attempting to resize my images on upload through Grocery Crud, but having some difficulty as I'm not sure how to access what is in the POST array so I can use it in my code.

Here is the section of my controller that does the image uploading (specifically the bit where I do the callback:

```
//Set up a call back function after the file has been uploaded to resize the image to save bandwidth/load times when displayed on the site
        $crud->callback_before_insert(array($this, 'resize_image'));
```

And here is the function that I'm calling:

```
private function resize_image ($post_array) 
    {
        $file_uploaded = $post_array (['image_url']);

        $config = array (
        'image_library' => 'gd2',
        'source_image'  => $file_uploaded,
        'create_thumb' => FALSE,
        'maintain_ratio' => TRUE,
        'width'  => 400,
        'height' => 300);

        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);

        $this->image_lib->resize();

    }
```

The upload still works fine (i.e. no errors) but the image remains at its original size. I'm sure it's something to do with what I'm populating the `$file_uploaded` variable with, but I don't know how to see what is being posted by Grocery CRUD to see what I should be using. I do have the CI profiler turned on, but I think Grocery CRUD redirects on it's processing of an uploaded before you get chance to see what's posted.

Can anyone help??

Answer (score 0):

You have to resize the image after successful upload. Check the below link for more details.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/image_lib.html